# How to group all the lines where first line starts with a pattern in java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a document whose pages are in sqlite data base. Each page looks something like this:

```
<ar>some words in arabic</ar> :Some more words in arabic and urdu mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>: some more mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>again urdu arabic mixed
<ar>some words in arabic</ar> :Some more words in arabic and urdu mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>: some more mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>again urdu arabic mixed
Few lines in arabic urdu
Again sample line <ar>some arabic</ar> again mix
Again mixed
<ar>some words in arabic</ar> :Some more words in arabic and urdu mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>: some more mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>again urdu arabic mixed
<ar>some words in arabic</ar> :Some more words in arabic and urdu mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>: some more mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>again urdu arabic mixed
<ar>some words in arabic</ar> :Some more words in arabic and urdu mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>: some more mixed <ar>again arabic</ar>again urdu arabic mixed
Few lines in arabic urdu
Again sample line <ar>some arabic</ar> again mix
Again mixed
```

That said, I need to insert the line starting with `<ar>` or groups of lines, where the first line starts with `<ar>` tag into seperate rows in sqlite.
So the flow should be like

1. Select first line starting with `<ar>` tag.
2. If the next line does not starts with `<ar>`, add it to the selection and repeat. Else insert this selection as a new row in sqlite.
   I don't know how to do this in Sqlite  or using java.
   Can anyone help me out?

**edit**
Here's the table structure for existing pages

```
CREATE TABLE Content (
 PageNo integer primary key autoincrement,
 PageText string
)
```

Table structure for new line(s)

```
CREATE TABLE Words (
 Id Integer primary key autoincrement,
 PageNo integer,
 WordLines
)
```

I have to insert the selected lines into the column `WordLines`.

**edit:**
The function

```
String pageText = getPageText(pageNum);
String[] wordLines = getWordLines(pageText);
for(int i=0, i<wordLines.length, i++) {
 insertIntoDB(wordLines[i], pageNum);
}
```

I am not able to figure out the implementation of the function `getWordLines()`.

Comment: Any attempts that you are facing trouble with? If this question is related to sqlite then it would help if you describe the structure of your tables. If not, then please remove the tag to clear any confusion

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad. I have added the structure.

Comment: OK. What is the trouble you are facing? Seems like it can be done if you just write an algorithm that loops through all lines and matches the criteria you specified. What is stopping you?

Comment: The problem is I am having a problem figuring out how to match and group the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java to split each document into a string array of the strings that you want to be your records. For example, once you have the text of a document as a string named `documentText`, use

```
string[] stringArray = documentText.split(“[\r\n]+(?=<ar>)”);
```

which splits the document at points where there is one or more newline characters followed by `<ar>`.

You can do this for each document in your table and insert the strings in `stringArray` into a temporary table as you go. Or you can keep them all in memory until you insert them all back into the table.